# What is the difference in pom.xml for plugin vs dependency (defining)?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am new to maven. I have watched some introductory videos and have gone through the documentation (it is all a bit daunting).

The identification of a plugin and a dependency appears similar.

I am looking at the ambari-2.7.6 pom.xml and the build fails at finding artifacts for

org.apache.maven.plugins (and atlassian clover)

The group id, artifact id and version tags appear to be the same for a plugin and a dependency.  Given that, if I poke around mvn repo, despite it saying (eg.), maven-javadoc-plugin for the page header, url, etc, the code tags start with .

The groupid and artifactid are the same in both cases but still the build throws

"plugin could not be resolved" errors.

I drilled through

https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

and found maven-javadoc-plugin with a 3.2.1-SNAPSHOT id.

The Ambari pom.xml part for this repository has a 'snapshot' true and 'releases' false. So I gather it will get any version, probably the latest, but seems to be getting none at all.  I tried adding a version also - 3.2.2-SNAPSHOT - but same errors.

> ```
>   <id>javadoc</id>
>   <build>
>     <plugins>
>       <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>         <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>3.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <configuration>
>           <docfilessubdirs>true</docfilessubdirs>
>         </configuration>
>         <executions>
>           <execution>
>             <id>attach-javadocs</id>
>             <goals>
>               <goal>jar</goal>
>             </goals>
>           </execution>
>         </executions>
>       </plugin>
>     </plugins>
>   </build>
> ```

Comment: Please add the complete error message and your pom.xml to your question.

Comment: `Description Resource Path Location Type
Plugin could not be resolved. Ensure the plugin's groupId, artifactId and version are present.
Additional information: Unable to resolve org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin pom.xml /apache-ambari-2.7.6-src line 653 Language Servers`

The pom.xml is the one that comes with apache-ambari-2.7.6-src so it is a bit large

Comment: Here is the javadoc portion which has an error

Comment: Please add the error message to your question, properly formatted, not as a comment.

Comment: `Plugin could not be resolved. Ensure the plugin's groupId, artifactId and version are present.

Additional information: Unable to resolve org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin`

Comment: It is 2 lines, there is not much to re-format.